# How can I keep hover during scrolling or how detect NOT scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have huge green div blocks (with screen height). When I hover one of  them- it change it's color to yellow and the image in the block 'slidesup'. When i scroll- the block's color roll back to green (and the image 'slidesdouwn)', and after stopping the scroll- the block becomes yeallow again (and image 'slidesup' again). How can i keep div block hovered, during my scroll?

```
<div class="news-block"><img scr=''></div>
<div class="news-block"><img scr=''></div>
<div class="news-block"><img scr=''></div>
<div class="news-block"><img scr=''></div>
<div class="news-block"><img scr=''></div>
<div class="news-block"><img scr=''></div>

<style>
    .news-block {
        width: 33%;
        color: green;
        height: 700px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(".news-block").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css({color: 'yellow'});
            $(this).find('img').slideUp(180, function() {});
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css({color: 'green'});
            $(this).find('img').slideDown(180, function() {});
        }
    );
</script>
```

**ADDED. Or may be i can unhover only when an user doesnt scroll? How can i detect NOT scrolling?**

```
$(".news-block").on('mouseover',
    function () {
        $(this).find('.event-info').stop().hide().css({opacity: 0});
        $(this).find('.picture-block').stop().slideUp(180, function() {
            $(this).find('.news-text').stop().show().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
            $(this).find('#voting-block').stop().show().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        });
    }
);


$(".news-block").on('mouseout',
    function () {
        --------------if not scrooll do the next ---------------
        $(this).find('.event-info').stop().hide().css({opacity: 0});
        $(this).find('.picture-block').stop().slideUp(180, function() {
            $(this).find('.news-text').stop().show().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
            $(this).find('#voting-block').stop().show().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Add a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for the hover effect?

Comment: Beacuse I should "slideDown" some elements in block too

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS hover, which will work during scroll as well, and can slide down an image.

```css
.news-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
  height: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.news-block img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -120px;
  transition: top 1s;
}
.news-block:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
.news-block:hover img {
  top: 20px;
  transition: top 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-block">
  <img src="http://lorempizza.com/200/120" alt="pizza">
</div>
<div class="news-block">
  <img src="http://lorempizza.com/200/120" alt="pizza">
</div>
<div class="news-block">
  <img src="http://lorempizza.com/200/120" alt="pizza">
</div>
```